# Somebody broke into my house

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

Last night, someone broke in.

I came home and found the back door open, and a window smashed. I did I quick search of the house and, miraculously, found *nothing* had been stolen. The thief must have scarpered....

Anyway, as I checked upstairs, I found a piece of paper on my bed. It seemed like a riddle, but it also seemed like something else... Here it is:

[image]

I also transcribed it:

> Camera runs out, my battery ends as our proof of error
> Only thing as we unfurl really wonderful words for terror
> Not me, my eye drops a tear, growing in size for the drops keep coming
> Sometimes the ever clear irony now erases many reroutes, or ones forthcoming
> Effort used any real time I run, as infinite stars rush ever past
> Crying when times run out, for wry sorrow who came last
> Unusual whirr roils inside, even last night may take a part
> The even and odd mayhem yet mirror the turn roamed at heart
> In the joyful spirit that is playing my number growing loyal
> Very large end that gold, silver and myrrh rewards can’t foil
> Every end has a hero rescuing someone as a rule or symbol
> Any apparent silly rule broken may know what you did
> Because rural cars ruined hirer will tell you what is forbid

**What is the thief's message?**

---HINTS---

Step 1:

> The direction in which the first part is written, may clue to find ________ words which are in a line, and the line below

> His answer
> Is his solution
> Now is correct
> The time is now
> Solve the puzzle

Comment: I have checked this over many times, but I still may have missed something as it is multi-layered. Apologies if I miss out anything

Comment: +1 for the amazingly good handwriting... assuming it is yours.

Comment: @stackreader - so consistently neat, they could probably make it into a font. ;)

Comment: What @Alconja said :)

Comment: Yes, I have very consistent handwriting :P

Comment: consecutive ab... :p

Comment: @jeyejow that's the first step ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil also the way the words rhyme it goes like AA BB CC DD EE F GG, dont know if thats intendedor no :p

Comment: @jeyejow nah rhymes are just for surface reading

Comment: coming to rhyme with forthcoming D:

Comment: @n_palum once this is solved you'll see I didn't have that many rhyme options ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first letters of each line spell

> CONSECUTIVE A/B.

Combined with the hint, this tells us to

> look at all the words that appear on two consecutive lines. (For instance, "as" appears on lines 1 and 2, "for" appears on lines 2 and 3...)
>
>  These words are unique for each pair of consecutive lines. Reading off their first letters gives "AFTER LETTER Y".

OPs Note:

> This seemed to confuse people, and I apologise because I don't feel like I chose the right terminology. AB made people think of rhymes or alphabet. Maybe XY would have been better but then there would have problem the the next step. Consecutive also doesn't really describe this process, but this can be improved in future puzzles

This is a clear instruction to

> look at the letters that appear after each Y. These spell out "BETWEEN RR IS THE FINAL REMARK" (with an extra OO at the end, necessary for making the Y in the previous step).

And this tells us to

> look at letters occurring between Rs. (For example, "camera runs" has an A between two Rs.)

Doing that gives us the final message:

> **Apologies, wrong house**.

Comment: Still should've stolen something anyway... Like Gareth's work towards the answer ;)

Comment: @n_palum rude/abusive; flagged. ;)